# Number of Databases based on Tier

Tags: google-cloud-sql

Is there a document or refference we can look at to dimension how many databases would be the recommended maximum based on the Tier type

e.g.:

db-n1-standard-1
1vCPU, 3.75 GB

or

db-n1-standard-2
2vCPU, 7.5 GB

Answer (score 1):

Number of databases is not a good indicator for choosing your tier.

You can have an instance with a 100 databases with little activity on a small instance, a single large database that needs a lot of memory and so forth.

You need to take into consideration how big you expect each database to be, how much data you expect to be kept in the cache, how many read/write queries you expect to be handling and so on.

The usual recommendation is to run load tests using your expected workloads and determine the machine requirements based on that.